# Update parent and child collections on generic repository with EF Core

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

Say I have a `Sale` class:

```
public class Sale : BaseEntity //BaseEntity only has an Id  
{        
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And an `Item` class:

```
public class Item : BaseEntity //BaseEntity only has an Id  
{
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }
}
```

And a Generic Repository (update method):

```
    public async Task<int> UpdateAsync<T>(T entity, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigations) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        var dbEntity = _dbContext.Set<T>().Find(entity.Id);

        var dbEntry = _dbContext.Entry(dbEntity);

        dbEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);            

        foreach (var property in navigations)
        {
            var propertyName = property.GetPropertyAccess().Name;

            await dbEntry.Collection(propertyName).LoadAsync();

            List<BaseEntity> dbChilds = dbEntry.Collection(propertyName).CurrentValue.Cast<BaseEntity>().ToList();

            foreach (BaseEntity child in dbChilds)
            {
                if (child.Id == 0)
                {
                    _dbContext.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    _dbContext.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
        }

        return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

I'm having difficulties to update the `Item` collection on the `Sale` class. With this code I managed to `add` or `modify` an `Item`. But, when I `delete` some item on the `UI` layer, nothing gets deleted.

Does `EF Core` have something to deal with this situation, while using a generic repository patter?

UPDATE

Seems to be that `Items` tracking is lost. Here is my generic retrieve method with includes.

```
    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync<T>(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        var query = _dbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

        if (includes != null)
        {
            query = includes.Aggregate(query,
              (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }

        return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently the question is for applying modifications of [disconnected entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) (otherwise you won't need to do anything else than calling `SaveChanges`) containing collection navigation properties which need to reflect the added/removed/update items from the passed object.

EF Core does not provide such out of the box capability. It supports simple [upsert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#mix-of-new-and-existing-entities) (insert or update) through `Update` method for entities with auto-generated keys, but it doesn't detect and delete the removed items.

So you need to do that detection yourself. Loading the existing items is a step in the right direction. The problem with your code is that it doesn't account the new items, but instead is doing some useless state manipulation of the existing items retrieved from the database.

Following is the correct implementation of the same idea. It uses some EF Core internals (`IClrCollectionAccessor` returned by the `GetCollectionAccessor()` method - both require `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;`) to manipulate the collection, but your code already is using the internal `GetPropertyAccess()` method, so I guess that shouldn't be a problem - in case something is changed in some future EF Core version, the code should be updated accordingly. The collection accessor is needed because while `IEnumerable<BaseEntity>` can be used for generically accessing the collections due to covariance, the same cannot be said about `ICollection<BaseEntity>` because it's invariant, and we need a way to access `Add` / `Remove` methods. The internal accessor provides that capability as well as a way to generically retrieve the property value from the passed entity.

**Update:** Starting from EF Core 3.0, [GetCollectionAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.navigationextensions.getcollectionaccessor?view=efcore-3.0) and [IClrCollectionAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iclrcollectionaccessor?view=efcore-3.0) are part of the public API.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync<T>(T entity, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigations) where T : BaseEntity
{
    var dbEntity = await _dbContext.FindAsync<T>(entity.Id);

    var dbEntry = _dbContext.Entry(dbEntity);
    dbEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

    foreach (var property in navigations)
    {
        var propertyName = property.GetPropertyAccess().Name;
        var dbItemsEntry = dbEntry.Collection(propertyName);
        var accessor = dbItemsEntry.Metadata.GetCollectionAccessor();

        await dbItemsEntry.LoadAsync();
        var dbItemsMap = ((IEnumerable<BaseEntity>)dbItemsEntry.CurrentValue)
            .ToDictionary(e => e.Id);

        var items = (IEnumerable<BaseEntity>)accessor.GetOrCreate(entity);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (!dbItemsMap.TryGetValue(item.Id, out var oldItem))
                accessor.Add(dbEntity, item);
            else
            {
                _dbContext.Entry(oldItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
                dbItemsMap.Remove(item.Id);
            }
        }

        foreach (var oldItem in dbItemsMap.Values)
            accessor.Remove(dbEntity, oldItem);
    }

    return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The algorithm is pretty standard. After loading the collection from the database, we create a dictionary containing the existing items keyed by Id (for fast lookup). Then we do a single pass over the new items. We use the dictionary to find the corresponding existing item. If no match is found, the item is considered new and is simply added to the target (tracked) collection. Otherwise the found item is updated from the source, and removed from the dictionary. This way, after finishing the loop, the dictionary contains the items that needs to be deleted, so all we need is remove them from the target (tracked) collection.

And that's all. The rest of the work will be done by the EF Core change tracker - the added items to the target collection will be marked as `Added`, the updated - either `Unchanged` or `Modified`, and the removed items, depending of the delete cascade behavior will be either be marked for deletion or update (disassociate from parent). If you want to force deletion, simply replace

```
accessor.Remove(dbEntity, oldItem);
```

with

```
_dbContext.Remove(oldItem);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! `Remove` does not have that overload, but the `accessor.Remove(...)` did the job.

Comment: Started anothe bounty because I miss-clicked on the bounty button and gave it to another person.

Comment: Both methods work, just the context one has single argument (silly typo - thanks for pointing out, corrected). But removing from the collection looks technically more correct anyway. Glad you like it, cheers :)

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: One additional question: If the navigation properties have different Id types (int or Guid) - how can this be considered?

Comment: @Julida It would be harder, mainly because can't use typed `Dictionary` and `Id` property accessor. `BaseEntity` class here helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. I found a solution for this.

Comment: Hi @Julida, what was the solution you found? I'm very interested. Thanks.

Comment: @craigmoliver I answered your question in a new answer (too many characters for a comment), see below

Comment: @IvanStoev Since EF Core 3.0 the GetCollectionAccessor() is part of the public API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.navigationextensions.getcollectionaccessor?view=efcore-3.0

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you,,,instead of Base entity can i useTEntity.?  my baseRepo 
 Repository<TEntity, TId> and TId is public interface IEntity<TId> 
    {
        TId Id { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @Ajt Nope, because we re manipulating sub collections of `TEntity` (e.g. `Person.Blogs`), which element type is different. The base entity here is needed to get access to the `Id` property. Interface can be used in general, but not generic like yours, i.e. here `((IEnumerable<BaseEntity>)dbItemsEntry.CurrentValue).ToDictionary(e => e.Id)` we need a cast to something non generic having known type `Id` property. Your scenario requires slightly different approach than present here - probably with moving part of the code in a generic method and calling it via reflection.

Comment: Am new .net core..can u pls provide non generic method ..i have added questions,,pls check.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63352197/update-parent-and-child-collections-on-tentity-generic-repository

Answer (score 5):

@craigmoliver Here's my solution. It is not the best, I know - if you find a more elegant way, please share.

Repository:

```
public async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync<TEntity, TId>(TEntity entity, bool save = true, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigations)
            where TEntity : class, IIdEntity<TId>
        {
            TEntity dbEntity = await _context.FindAsync<TEntity>(entity.Id);

        EntityEntry<TEntity> dbEntry = _context.Entry(dbEntity);
        dbEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

        foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> property in navigations)
        {
            var propertyName = property.GetPropertyAccess().Name;
            CollectionEntry dbItemsEntry = dbEntry.Collection(propertyName);
            IClrCollectionAccessor accessor = dbItemsEntry.Metadata.GetCollectionAccessor();

            await dbItemsEntry.LoadAsync();
            var dbItemsMap = ((IEnumerable<object>)dbItemsEntry.CurrentValue)
                .ToDictionary(e => string.Join('|', _context.FindPrimaryKeyValues(e)));

            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)accessor.GetOrCreate(entity))
            {
                if (!dbItemsMap.TryGetValue(string.Join('|', _context.FindPrimaryKeyValues(item)), out object oldItem))
                {
                    accessor.Add(dbEntity, item);
                }
                else
                {
                    _context.Entry(oldItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
                    dbItemsMap.Remove(string.Join('|', _context.FindPrimaryKeyValues(item)));
                }
            }

            foreach (var oldItem in dbItemsMap.Values)
            {
                accessor.Remove(dbEntity, oldItem);
                await DeleteAsync(oldItem as IEntity, false);

            }
        }

        if (save)
        {
            await SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

Context:

```
 public IReadOnlyList<IProperty> FindPrimaryKeyProperties<T>(T entity)
        {
            return Model.FindEntityType(entity.GetType()).FindPrimaryKey().Properties;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> FindPrimaryKeyValues<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
        {
            return from p in FindPrimaryKeyProperties(entity)
                   select entity.GetPropertyValue(p.Name);
        }
```

Comment: If my class has 2 set of  collections then how to call this function ?..thanks

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to just get all `Deleted` entities, cast them to `BaseEntity` and check their IDs to the current IDs in the entity's relationship collection.

Something along the lines of:

```
foreach (var property in navigations)
{
    var propertyName = property.GetPropertyAccess().Name;

    await dbEntry.Collection(propertyName).LoadAsync();

    // this line specifically might need some changes
    // as it may give you ICollection<SomeType>
    var currentCollectionType = property.GetPropertyAccess().PropertyType;

    var deletedEntities = _dbContext.ChangeTracker
        .Entries
        .Where(x => x.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted && x.GetType() == currentCollectionType)
        .Select(x => (BaseEntity)x.Id)
        .ToArray();

    List<BaseEntity> dbChilds = dbEntry.Collection(propertyName).CurrentValue.Cast<BaseEntity>().ToList();

    foreach (BaseEntity child in dbChilds)
    {
        if (child.Id == 0)
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        if (deletedEntities.Contains(child.Id))
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `deletedEntities` array has no items, even if I remove the `Type` conditional

Comment: peeking into the `ChangeTracker` I notices that `Item` objects are state `Unchanged`

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto This assumes that you called `_dbContext.Remove(item)` which fills the ChangeTracker with those deleted entities