# Update parent and child collections on TEntity generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My Base repository Class

```cs
public class Repository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
{       
    protected readonly CBSContext _context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> _entities;
  
    public Repository(CBSContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        _entities = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    
    public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified);
       
    }

    //Update child enitity code added below 
}
```

And my Entity Interface

```cs
public interface IEntity<TId> 
{
    TId Id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
}
```

I need to Add/update/delete child entities in disconnected  scenarious.

AM referencing this answer [Add/update/delete child entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190929/7273263)

And that anser is based on custom BaseEnity but i am using IEnity..

Works done:

i  have replace baseentity with Tentity. but Showing error

Below is new Code for save child elements

```cs
public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigations)
{
    var dbEntity = await _context.FindAsync<TEntity>(entity.Id);

    var dbEntry = _context.Entry(dbEntity);
    dbEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

    foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> property in navigations)
    {
        var propertyName = property.GetPropertyAccess().Name;
        var dbItemsEntry = dbEntry.Collection(propertyName);
        var accessor = dbItemsEntry.Metadata.GetCollectionAccessor();

        await dbItemsEntry.LoadAsync();
        var dbItemsMap = ((IEnumerable<TEntity>)dbItemsEntry.CurrentValue)
            .ToDictionary(e => e.Id);

        var items = (IEnumerable<object>) accessor.GetOrCreate(entity);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (!dbItemsMap.TryGetValue(item.Id, out var oldItem))
                accessor.Add(dbEntity, item);
            else
            {
                _context.Entry(oldItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
                dbItemsMap.Remove(item.Id);
            }
        }

        foreach (var oldItem in dbItemsMap.Values)
            accessor.Remove(dbEntity, oldItem);
    }

    await Task.Run(() => _context.SaveChangesAsync());
}
```

Below Showing Error:

[image]

Is There any alternate approach..am new to .net core ..Please suggest if any alternate approach.

Comment: unrelated but why are you offloading things like this `await Task.Run(() => _context.SaveChangesAsync())`

Comment: thanks..i need a solution for add/update/delete child entiies..is there any alternate approach ?

Comment: Please show the error as text and not an image only.

Comment: My code not works for tentity class just confirmed with @ivon ( answered in linked question) ..I need alternate approach fr save parent and child enitities..

Comment: Please, try `dbItemsEntry.Query().AsEnumerable()` instead of `accessor.GetOrCreate(entity)`

Comment: thnks..error goes ..but cant access  item.Id .. i searching alternate solution,,if any non generic method pls let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 5.0):** Updated part of the code due to metadata interface changes and introduction of skip navigations. Note that the code **does not handle** many-to-many skip navigation properties.

```cs
// process navigations
foreach (var navEntry in dbEntry.Navigations)
{
    if (navEntry.Metadata is not INavigation navigation) continue; // skip navigation pproperty         
    if (!visited.Add(navigation.ForeignKey)) continue; // already processed
    await navEntry.LoadAsync();
    if (!navigation.IsCollection)
    {
        // reference type navigation property
        var refValue = navigation.GetGetter().GetClrValue(entity);
        navEntry.CurrentValue = refValue == null ? null :
            await context.UpdateGraphAsync(navEntry.CurrentValue, refValue, visited);
    }
    else
    {
        // collection type navigation property
        var accessor = navigation.GetCollectionAccessor();
        var items = (IEnumerable<object>)accessor.GetOrCreate(entity, false);
        var dbItems = (IEnumerable<object>)accessor.GetOrCreate(dbEntity, false);
        var itemType = navigation.TargetEntityType;
        var keyProperties = itemType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties
            .Select((p, i) => (Index: i, Getter: p.GetGetter(), Comparer: p.GetKeyValueComparer()))
            .ToList();
        var keyValues = new object[keyProperties.Count];
        void GetKeyValues(object sourceItem)
        {
            foreach (var p in keyProperties)
                keyValues[p.Index] = p.Getter.GetClrValue(sourceItem);
        }
        object FindItem(IEnumerable<object> targetCollection, object sourceItem)
        {
            GetKeyValues(sourceItem);
            foreach (var targetItem in targetCollection)
            {
                bool keyMatch = true;
                foreach (var p in keyProperties)
                {
                    (var keyA, var keyB) = (p.Getter.GetClrValue(targetItem), keyValues[p.Index]);
                    keyMatch = p.Comparer?.Equals(keyA, keyB) ?? object.Equals(keyA, keyB);
                    if (!keyMatch) break;
                }
                if (keyMatch) return targetItem;
            }
            return null;
        }
        // Remove db items missing in the current list
        foreach (var dbItem in dbItems.ToList())
            if (FindItem(items, dbItem) == null) accessor.Remove(dbEntity, dbItem);
        // Add current items missing in the db list, update others
        var existingItems = dbItems.ToList();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var dbItem = FindItem(existingItems, item);
            if (dbItem == null)
                accessor.Add(dbEntity, item, false);
            await context.UpdateGraphAsync(dbItem, item, visited);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Some additional questions arose from the comments. What to do with reference navigation properties and what to do if the related entities do not implement such generic interface, also the inability of compiler inferring the generic type arguments when using such generic method signature.

After thinking a bit I came to conclusion that no base class/interface (and even generic entity type) is needed at all, since EF Core metadata contains all information needed to work with PK (which is used by `Find` / `FindAsync` methods and change tracker for instance).

Following is a method which recursively applies disconnected entity graph modifications using only the EF Core metadata information/services. If needed, it could be modified to receive "exclusion" filter in case some entities/collections should be skipped:

```cs
public static class EntityGraphUpdateHelper
{
    public static async ValueTask<object> UpdateGraphAsync(this DbContext context, object entity) =>
        await context.UpdateGraphAsync(await context.FindEntityAsync(entity), entity, new HashSet<IForeignKey>());

    private static async ValueTask<object> UpdateGraphAsync(this DbContext context, object dbEntity, object entity, HashSet<IForeignKey> visited)
    {
        bool isNew = dbEntity == null;
        if (isNew) dbEntity = entity;
        var dbEntry = context.Entry(dbEntity);
        if (isNew)
            dbEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        else
        {
            // ensure is attached (tracked)
            if (dbEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
                dbEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            // update primitive values
            dbEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        }
        // process navigations
        foreach (var navEntry in dbEntry.Navigations)
        {
            if (!visited.Add(navEntry.Metadata.ForeignKey)) continue; // already processed
            await navEntry.LoadAsync();
            if (!navEntry.Metadata.IsCollection())
            {
                // reference type navigation property
                var refValue = navEntry.Metadata.GetGetter().GetClrValue(entity);
                navEntry.CurrentValue = refValue == null ? null :
                    await context.UpdateGraphAsync(navEntry.CurrentValue, refValue, visited);
            }
            else
            {
                // collection type navigation property
                var accessor = navEntry.Metadata.GetCollectionAccessor();
                var items = (IEnumerable<object>)accessor.GetOrCreate(entity, false);
                var dbItems = (IEnumerable<object>)accessor.GetOrCreate(dbEntity, false);
                var itemType = navEntry.Metadata.GetTargetType();
                var keyProperties = itemType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties
                    .Select((p, i) => (Index: i, Getter: p.GetGetter(), Comparer: p.GetKeyValueComparer()))
                    .ToList();
                var keyValues = new object[keyProperties.Count];
                void GetKeyValues(object sourceItem)
                {
                    foreach (var p in keyProperties)
                        keyValues[p.Index] = p.Getter.GetClrValue(sourceItem);
                }
                object FindItem(IEnumerable<object> targetCollection, object sourceItem)
                {
                    GetKeyValues(sourceItem);
                    foreach (var targetItem in targetCollection)
                    {
                        bool keyMatch = true;
                        foreach (var p in keyProperties)
                        {
                            (var keyA, var keyB) = (p.Getter.GetClrValue(targetItem), keyValues[p.Index]);
                            keyMatch = p.Comparer?.Equals(keyA, keyB) ?? object.Equals(keyA, keyB);
                            if (!keyMatch) break;
                        }
                        if (keyMatch) return targetItem;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                // Remove db items missing in the current list
                foreach (var dbItem in dbItems.ToList())
                    if (FindItem(items, dbItem) == null) accessor.Remove(dbEntity, dbItem);
                // Add current items missing in the db list, update others
                var existingItems = dbItems.ToList();
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var dbItem = FindItem(existingItems, item);
                    if (dbItem == null)
                        accessor.Add(dbEntity, item, false);
                    await context.UpdateGraphAsync(dbItem, item, visited);
                }
            }
        }
        return dbEntity;
    }

    public static ValueTask<object> FindEntityAsync(this DbContext context, object entity)
    {
        var entityType = context.Model.FindRuntimeEntityType(entity.GetType());
        var keyProperties = entityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties;
        var keyValues = new object[keyProperties.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < keyValues.Length; i++)
            keyValues[i] = keyProperties[i].GetGetter().GetClrValue(entity);
        return context.FindAsync(entityType.ClrType, keyValues);
    }
}
```

Please note that similar to EF Core methods, `SaveChangesAsync` call is not part of the above method, and it should be called separately afterwards.

**Original:**

Handling collections of entities implementing such *generic* interface requires slightly different approach, since there is no *non generic* base class / interface to be used for extracting the `Id`.

One possible solution is to move the collection handling code to a separate *generic* method and call it dynamically or via reflection.

For instance (use the VS to determine the necessary `using`s):

```cs
public static class EntityUpdateHelper
{
    public static async Task UpdateEntityAsync<TEntity, TId>(this DbContext context, TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigations)
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
    {
        var dbEntity = await context.FindAsync<TEntity>(entity.Id);
        var dbEntry = context.Entry(dbEntity);
        dbEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        foreach (var property in navigations)
        {
            var propertyName = property.GetPropertyAccess().Name;
            var dbItemsEntry = dbEntry.Collection(propertyName);
            var dbItems = dbItemsEntry.CurrentValue;
            var items = dbItemsEntry.Metadata.GetGetter().GetClrValue(entity);
            // Determine TEntity and TId, and call UpdateCollection<TEntity, TId>
            // via reflection
            var itemType = dbItemsEntry.Metadata.GetTargetType().ClrType;
            var idType = itemType.GetInterfaces()
                .Single(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntity<>))
                .GetGenericArguments().Single();
            var updateMethod = typeof(EntityUpdateHelper).GetMethod(nameof(UpdateCollection))
                .MakeGenericMethod(itemType, idType);
            updateMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { dbItems, items });
        }

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public static void UpdateCollection<TEntity, TId>(this DbContext context, ICollection<TEntity> dbItems, ICollection<TEntity> items)
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
    {
        var dbItemsMap = dbItems.ToDictionary(e => e.Id);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (!dbItemsMap.TryGetValue(item.Id, out var oldItem))
                dbItems.Add(item);
            else
            {
                context.Entry(oldItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
                dbItemsMap.Remove(item.Id);
            }
        }
        foreach (var oldItem in dbItemsMap.Values)
            dbItems.Remove(oldItem);
    }
}
```

and call it from `Customer` repository:

```cs
return await _context.UpdateEntityAsync(entity, e => e.Addresses);
```

In case of generic repository (no navigations argument), and all child collection entities implementing that interface, simple iterate the `dbEntry.Collections` property, e.g.

```cs
//foreach (var property in navigations)
foreach (var dbItemsEntry in dbEntry.Collections)
{
    //var propertyName = property.GetPropertyAccess().Name;
    //var dbItemsEntry = dbEntry.Collection(propertyName);
    var dbItems = dbItemsEntry.CurrentValue;
    var items = dbItemsEntry.Metadata.GetGetter().GetClrValue(entity);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: wow! thanks a lot ..one more help if class contains another i.e Documents.. Same can i use same method return await _context.UpdateEntityAsync(entity, e => e.Addresses);

Comment: You can pass multiple collection accessors, e.g.  `_context.UpdateEntityAsync(entity, e => e.Addresses, e => e.Documens, ...)` if that's the question.

Comment: I've my Entity classes (partial classes) generated by EF Core scaffolding command. and I've used same names in the same namespace and inherited each of parent and child classes from IEntity<int> and I'm unable to call the method UpdateEntityAsync. I see the following compilation error. The type arguments for method 'EFCoreHelper.UpdateEntityAsync<TEntity, TId>(DBContext, TEntity)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (CS0411)

Comment: Update on my comment above, I don't have to implement the interface as the Id property already exists on all of my Classes as I've this primary key on all my tables 
```Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY```

Comment: @HarishMashetty Unfortunately the above generic method signature does not allow inferring the generic type args, so they have to be provided explicitly, e.g. `_context.UpdateEntityAsync<Customer, int>(...)`. If your entities use `int Id`, then consider using the approach from linked post, but instead of base class use non generic interface like `public interface IEntity { int Id { get; set; }`. It allows removing the second generic arg and inferring the first when calling it.

Comment: @IvanStoev Excellent. That works. I had to make couple of changes though but it works. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @IvanStoev By mistake I told customer has collection of documents but it is only one document (one to one). For the document  I have to update seperately rite?

Comment: &Ajt The original question from the linked post was for collection type properties only, so I didn't think about reference type navigation properties.  Most probably they can/have to be incorporated in the same method. Give me some time and I'll get back to you with solution.

Comment: There you go. The new method (at least by idea) should handle all type of navigations.

Comment: @IvanStoev It seems that Metadata.ForeignKey property is not available in EF Core 6.x? Are you familiar with an alternative?

Comment: @BeeCoding Code updated for EFC 5.0+.

Comment: @IvanStoev is there a sample project of this implementation for reference?

Comment: @SaTyA No, all the code was written specifically for (and is contained in the answer of) this question. It's basically a single custom extension method in the `EntityGraphUpdateHelper` class from the first update (with one region of code replaced with the one from the EFC 5.0+ update)