# Update parent and child (in one-to-one) with a generic method

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088933/update-parent-and-child-collections-on-generic-repository-with-ef-core), and liked how the generic update for one-to-many is implemented.

I tried to mimic it to implement a one-to-one version for myself but could not be totally successful. Following is the result of my struggle -

```cs
public async Task<int> UpdateAsync<T>(T entity, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigations) where T : EntityBase
{
    var dbEntity = await _DbCtx.FindAsync<T>(entity.Id);

    var entry = _DbCtx.Entry(dbEntity);
    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry);

    foreach (var nav in navigations)
    {
        string propertyName = nav.GetPropertyAccess().Name;        
        
        // Problem #01 //
        // if possible, I'd like to avoid this reflection in favor of EF Core MetaData?
        var child = (EntityBase)entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(entity);
        if (child == null)
            continue;            // if the client-sent model doesn't have child, skip

        var referenceEntry = entry.Reference(propertyName);
        await referenceEntry.LoadAsync();

        var dbChild = (EntityBase)referenceEntry.CurrentValue;
        if (dbChild == null)
        {
            // Problem #02 //
            // if the existing entity doesn't have child, the client-sent child will be assigned.
            // but I could not figure out how to do this
        }
        else
        {
            _DbCtx.Entry(dbChild).CurrentValues.SetValues(child);
        }
    }

    return await _DbCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I have marked the problems as `Problem #01` and `Problem #02` in code comments above. Any suggestion, solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit :**
Alternatively, if you think there is a better, more efficient way of doing the same thing I'm trying to do above, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Problem #01**, I couldn't find equivalent of `GetCollectionAccessor`, but one way I can think of solving it using `EF Core` metadata, would be calling the `Entry` method in the disconnected Entity:

```
var entry = _context.Entry(dbEntity);
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry);

var disconnectedEntry = _context.Entry(entity); // new

foreach (var nav in navigations)
{
    string propertyName = nav.GetPropertyAccess().Name;
    var navigationChild = disconnectedEntry.Navigation(propertyName).CurrentValue; // new
}
```

Bear in mind that in every `Entry` method call `EF Core` will try to DetectChanges. As this verification is not necessary for this Entity, you can save some performance disabling the `AutoDetectChanges` as [suggested in this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14404).

**Now for Problem #02**, you can just assign the child `Entity` to the `ReferenceEntry` CurrentValue, like this:

```
        var referenceEntry = entry.Reference(propertyName);
        await referenceEntry.LoadAsync();

        var dbChild = (EntityBase)referenceEntry.CurrentValue;
        if (dbChild == null)
        {
           referenceEntry.CurrentValue = navigationChild; // new
        }
        else
        {
            _DbCtx.Entry(dbChild).CurrentValues.SetValues(child);
        }
```

I hope it can help you. If some problem arises let me know!

#### Edit

I also suggest you to read about the [TrackGraph method](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/changetracker-trackgraph-ef-core.aspx). Depending on how your entities work, maybe everything could be done with this method with a couple of lines.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your neat answer. `in every Entry method call EF Core will try to DetectChanges` - where can I learn more about this? Or, is going through the source codes the only way to get such insights?

Comment: You're welcome
This has to do with how Entity Framework (and many other ORM's) use the [Unit of Work pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) to sync in-memory entities with the database. [This blog](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/changetracker-in-ef-core.aspx) has a nice explanation of how EF Core manage this, and it has also [another post](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-disconnected-entity-graph-ef-core.aspx) explaining some quirks of the ChangeTracking on disconnected entities. I'll add another suggestion on the answer.

Comment: I've been through the links you've provided at various points in the past. The reason I asked is, there was a time when I could get such small insights by simply looking at the MSDN documentation and I couldn't find anything about a possible performance penalty in the official documentation of `Entry` method. But after your answer I looked in the source code and found that the `Entry` method does in fact call a `TryDetectChanges` method.