# Entity Framework - Replace child collection using a detached model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a many-to-many relationship between Entity A and Entity B. Entity Framework has automatically created a junction table in SQL Server after running the migration. (I don't have this junction table defined anywhere in the code.) For example:

```
class EntityA
{
   // ...
   public ICollection<EntityB> Foo { get; set; }
}

class EntityB
{
   // ...
   public ICollection<EntityA> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I need to replace the `Foo` collection on `EntityA` using a (detached) list coming in from a client application. I've spent the better part of a day trying to figure this out. Here is what I've tried:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(EntityA someEntity)
{
        var entry = context.EntityA.Attach(someEntity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

        var collection = entry.Collection(x => x.Foo);
        collection.IsModified = true;

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I've also tried changing the `CurrentValue` property of `collection`, and obviously I've also tried replacing `Foo` directly, but nothing seems to work -- the junction table remains empty. How can this child list be entirely replaced without having to `Include()` / load the entire list into memory for manual tracking / removal?

Comment: What do you mean by replace. To delete  previous Foo  and assign a list of completely new ones entity B, or just remove previous foo from entity A and add  list of existing entity B?

Comment: The new list of Foo can contain new entities and existing entities (and whatever's not in it is a deleted entity). I suppose the easiest way to handle that would be to delete whatever's there in the DB and replace it with an entirely new list.

Comment: Without loading the original list from the database, EF Core has no way to know what to do with the modified list. Neither you btw. And there is no "delete something"  command w/o loading. It's just how the EF works - load/modify/save. You can try some extension from the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/ list, for instance [Detached Mapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#detached-mapper). It probably would help you not writing boilerplate code, but I doubt it won't  load the original collection "for you", since there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivan (in the comments above) is right. After some trial and error, I ended up writing an extension method that works for my case. Before I get to that, I want to credit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190929/1860415) for pointing me in the right direction, which I ended up modifying to get it working with auto-generated EF junction tables. First, the extension method:

```
    // assuming your models inherit from a base class or implement an interface
    public interface IEntity
    {
        Guid Id { get; set; } // or int or whatever your ID field is
    }

    public static class DbExtensions
    {
        // Updates the many-to-many child collections of an entity (for an auto-generated EF junction table)
        public static async Task UpdateJunctionTableAsync<T, Y>(this DbContext baseContext, T entity, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<Y>>> property)
            where T : class, IEntity
            where Y : class, IEntity
        {
            // scope these calls to a new context -- working off the base context
            // tends to cause issues down the line with the change tracking
            using var context = new DbContext();

            // EF internally compares with DB entities, so we'll do the same
            var dbEntity = await context.FindAsync<T>(entity.Id);
            var dbEntry = context.Entry(dbEntity);

            // access the collection entry that resulted in a junction table
            var dbItemsEntry = dbEntry.Collection(property);

            // get its associated CLR collection accessor
            var accessor = dbItemsEntry.Metadata.GetCollectionAccessor();

            // load the entry's items
            await dbItemsEntry.LoadAsync();

            // build a dictionary to track what needs to be added vs removed
            var dbItemsMap = dbItemsEntry.CurrentValue.ToDictionary(e => e.Id);

            // get the current items in the entity (not DB)
            var items = (IEnumerable<Y>)accessor.GetOrCreate(entity, false);

            // add them to the DB as needed
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                // if this already exists, no need to process it.
                if (dbItemsMap.ContainsKey(item.Id))
                    dbItemsMap.Remove(item.Id);
                else
                {
                    // otherwise, add a tracked version of it.
                    context.Set<Y>().Attach(item);
                    accessor.Add(dbEntity, item, false);
                }
            }

            // anything still left here has been deleted from the entity
            foreach (var oldItem in dbItemsMap.Values)
                accessor.Remove(dbEntity, oldItem);

            // we have to clear the junction table from the incoming model's collection,
            // otherwise EF will try to attach to it again, which will cause errors
            // further down the line
            var memberSelectorExpression = property.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberSelectorExpression != null)
            {
                var propertyInfo = memberSelectorExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
                if (propertyInfo != null)
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, null, null);
            }

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Using this is simple:

```
        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateFoo(EntityA model)
        {
            // update the junction table first
            await context.UpdateJunctionTableAsync(model, x => x.Foo);

            // then update whatever else you want
            // e.g., if we were updating the whole row:
            // context.EntityA.Attach(model).State = EntityState.Modified;

            // save
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
```